# Layout items are hidden

Tags: android

I have a relative layout and inside it, two linear. The first one has an image as background, and the second one have 4 buttons, one below the other.

```
<RelativeLayout  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout   android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg1">
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/header_layout_select"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/img
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"      android:orientation="vertical" >

<button .... >
<button .... >
<button .... >
<button .... >

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I would like the btn layout to be below of the img layout. My problem is that, if i run my app in a very small screen (2.7 inches for example) I can only see the 2 first buttons. I would like to see all the buttons.

Comment: We need to see your button attributes to provide answer of your question.

Comment: <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/trans"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

Answer (score 1):

You can add a VerticalScrollView
Like (pseudo code)

```
<RelativeLayout>
<ScrollView >
<Relativelayout>
<linearLayout>
</linear>
<linear>
<button> </button>
<button> </button>
<button> </button>
<button> </button>
</linear>
</relative>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If the screen is small, you can scroll down